I need to save multiple faces from n number of images
For example I have abc faces in image 1 and bcd faces in image 2.
I need to save a,b,c faces in image 1 folder and b,c,d faces in image 2 folder [as separate images].
I followed the below code which seems right, but only the first image's faces are getting saved in every other folder.
Here is the code:
def detect_bounding_boxes(root, file_, identification, hashmap):
    input_image_path = os.path.join(root, file_)
    resize_image(input_image_path)
    image_files = [file for file in os.listdir(root) if file.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'))]
    logging.info('Number of files in zip folder: %s', len(image_files))
    # Create a directory to save faces
    faces_folder = os.path.join(root, 'faces')
    os.makedirs(faces_folder, exist_ok=True)

    # Upscale and save faces from each input image
    output_folders = []
    for image_file in image_files:
        output_folder = f"upscaled_faces_{os.path.splitext(image_file)[0]}"
        image_path = os.path.join(root, image_file)
        shutil.copy(image_path, faces_folder)
        upscale_faces(input_image_path, output_folder)
        output_folders.append(output_folder)

    logging.info("All faces upscale and saved.")
    print("All faces upscale and saved.")

    os.makedirs(identification, exist_ok=True)

    # Verify faces in each upscaled folder
    for output_folder in output_folders:
        verify_faces_in_database_2(output_folder, identification, hashmap)
        shutil.rmtree(output_folder)

    logging.info("Verification complete and folders deleted.")
    print("Verification complete and folders deleted.")



def upscale_faces(input_image_path, output_folder):
    img = cv2.imread(input_image_path)
    a = YoloDetector()
    # Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

    # Extract bounding boxes from the response
    bounding_boxes = a.predict(img)[0]
    logging.info('facial features: %s', bounding_boxes)

    # Load the original image
    original_image = Image.open(input_image_path)

    # Convert the image to RGB mode if it has an alpha channel
    if original_image.mode == 'RGBA':
        original_image = original_image.convert('RGB')

    # Create output folder if it doesn't exist
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

    # Iterate over bounding boxes
    for bbox_group_idx, bbox_group in enumerate(bounding_boxes, start=1):
        for i, bounding_box in enumerate(bbox_group, start=1):
            left, top, right, bottom = bounding_box
            # print('bounding box: ', bounding_box)

            # Crop the face from the original image
            face_image = original_image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

            output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f'face_{bbox_group_idx}_{i}.jpg')
            face_image.save(output_path)
            logging.info(f"Face {bbox_group_idx}_{i} cropped and saved successfully.")
            print(f"Face {bbox_group_idx}_{i} cropped and saved successfully.")

